# Smritis for Brahma-Vadinis

Tags: smriti, brahmavadini

Is there a set of practices that have been established for Brahmavadinis when they come out of their monthly asaucha periods? Are there any smritis which describe what their duties should be and if they can study (veda-adhyayana) during these times? If not, do the smritis declare what practices they should do to restart the study?